# CRM 2015 on premise: Plugin Profiler error

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Note: We cannot use remote debugger bcoz of limitations.

I have used Plugin profiler in the past, but never faced this error or any issues.

I have tried some solutions by Aileen but no luck. (http://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.com/2014/05/debug-crm-2013-using-plugin-profiler.html)

Am getting this below error in my new assignment. Anybody know whats going on?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unexpected Exception in the Plug-in ProfilerDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220891</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>OperationStatus</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">3</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>SubErrorCode</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">-2146233088</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>Unexpected Exception in the Plug-in Profiler</Message>
  <Timestamp>2017-04-25T16:46:17.1055295Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[PluginProfiler.Plugins: PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerPlugin]
[fd941d99-d629-e711-810c-005056ab45d6: ABCcorp.Xrm.MyProject.Plugins.MyPlugin: Pre Update of new_myentity with Pre Image (Profiler)]

An exception occurred during the initialization of the Plug-in Profiler.
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrImmutable()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxClientBase`1.Open()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxClientBase`1.get_Proxy()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationService.ProcessException(Exception e, SandboxSdkClient client)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationService.Execute(String operation, Byte[] serializedRequest)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]&amp; outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.ISandboxOrganizationService.Execute(String operation, Byte[] serializedRequest)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper.ExecuteInternal(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper.RetrieveInternal(String entityName, Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper.Retrieve(String entityName, Guid entityId, ColumnSet columnSet)
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PluginLoaderUtility.RefreshAssembly(IOrganizationService service, ProfilerConfiguration config, PluginInitializationContext context)
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PluginLoaderUtility.RefreshPluginInitializationContext(IOrganizationServiceFactory factory, ProfilerConfiguration config, PluginInitializationContext currentContext)
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerBase`1.InitializeProfiler(Dictionary`2 services, T operationContext, ProfilerPluginContext&amp; context)



</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Comment: this is happening after installed the profiler, profiled the plugin step & while repro the plugin execution scenario by CRM UI update.

Comment: Is it CRM online or on premise?

Comment: Apologies, I see from the heading it is on premise!

Comment: We have tried different SDK versions, but same issue persists. Is there any other directions to solve this error - many of our developers are struggling with this :(

Comment: I would consider raising this with Microsoft as there seems to be an issue with the Sandbox processing service. Could be specific to the version of CRM you are on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple thoughts...

1. From what version of the SDK are you using the Plugin Profiler? Does it match the version of CRM?
2. I generally like to have my plugin code also available via a Console app so that I can debug and step through it without any profiling, remote debugging, etc.

This article shows how to get started with a console app that connects to CRM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602970.aspx

My typical architecture is to have a Visual Studio shared project that contains all the business logic, and then a Plugin project and a Console project, each of which gets the target record and passes it into the shared project.

For example:
[a visual studio folder containing typical plugin projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcaN8.jpg)

Comment: Actually our crm is 2015 onpremise 7.0, but we tried with latest sdk 2015 7.1 and also 365 sdk - nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your sandbox processing service is in a faulted state. I would restart that process as that usually resolves the issue. This service should be on the same box as the Async Processing service, but can be in a different location I believe.

Either way, locate and restart "Microsoft Dynamics CRM Sandbox Processing Service"

If that doesn't work reboot the box it is located on.

That usually resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Conor. Though I did that in the past.. I tried again now but no luck.