# CRM Trace Logs Showing an Exception

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

We are debugging a campaign plugin in CRM. We are relying on using the D365 Plugin Trace Log since the the Plugin Profiler is also throwing an error.

We are getting an exception that the Sandbox.Helper DLL is not found.
We have confirmed from the BIN that that DLL is available. We also have tried setting the mode of the plugin to None and Isolated. We have restarted the sandbox asynch service,crmapppool, and the other D365 services in the CRM server.

[image: Plugin Trace Log Error in CRM]

Comment: Is this for CRM on-premise?

Comment: Started happening without any changes from your side, surfacing in all environments? Any other plugin working/debugging without issues? Probably need a ticket with MS support, in case of some server patches or updates creating troubles.

Comment: On a side note, sometimes we will never able to overcome some errors. I faced this in the past - https://stackoverflow.com/q/43616768/7920473. Check the suggestions which helped me as a workaround

Comment: Yes, this is on-premise. No, we are not able to debug anything using the plugin profiler or the CRM Trace Log.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your plugin assembly has references to other assemblies except those of the .NET Framework and the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk dll's.

Referenced assemblies can only be used when you merge them into the plugin assembly, e.g. using ILMerge or ILRepack.